# Pass OneToOne relationships to Django Templates

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to setup a OneToOne relationship in Django in order to show data from `TableA` and `TableB` for a specific record.

I am having issues figuring out how to display it in my view, examples are out there but some seem a bit outdated or have solutions that I am not familiar with.

I have tried with some different calls in the views file as well as in my templates file without any luck, any input would be highly appreciated!

**My models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class tableA(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=None)
    published = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None)
    publisher = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=True, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'tableA'
        unique_together = (("publisher", "published"),)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.created

class tableB(models.Model):
    tableA = models.OneToOneField(tableA, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, default=None)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None, null=True)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tableA.code
```

**My views.py**

```
def nani(request):

    data = TableA.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'site/home.html', {'data':data})
```

**My template**

```
{% for test in data %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ test.published }}</td>
        <td>{{ test.publisher }}</td>
        <td>{{ test.TableB.url }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Try replaing `<td>{{ test.TableB.url }}</td>` with `<td>{{ test.tableB.url }}</td>`.

Comment: But this, I think, will throw an exception when `tableA.tableB` does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the uppercase/lowercase letters are like you said, just do this, I just tested it.

***views.py***

```
from .models import tableA

def nani(request):
    data = tableA.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'site/home.html', {'data': data})
```

in your ***site/home.html*** :

```
{% for test in data %}
    {{ test.published }}
    {{ test.publisher }}
    {{ test.tableb.url }}
{% endfor %}
```

and also something wrong about your **str** method. datetime is not a string format. so in your ***models.py***, you have to fix this line like this:

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.created)
```